# Load bundle from different host

Tags: webpack

I'm building a single page app using webpack to build a `main.<hash>.js`, `main.<hash>.css` and `index.html` with HtmlWebpackPlugin.

This injects the bundle into the `index.html` as

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.4d67bd1c.js"></script>`

in body, and

`<link href="/static/css/main.f6908217.css" rel="stylesheet">`

in head.

How can I include the host in the href and src? I have tried using a custom template with HtmlWebpackPlugin, but I'm unsure how to get the path to the compiled bundle js/css.

HtmlWebpackPlugin is configured as follows:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    template: paths.appHtml,
    minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
    }
})
```

(This is basically straight from create-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html-webpack-plugin` respects the [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) option of your webpack config. You can set the public path to your host and it will automatically add it to the assets. For example with this configuration:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].[hash:6].js',
  publicPath: 'https://myhost.com/'
}
```

The bundle is included as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myhost.com/main.1ae0e6.js"></script>
```

If you prefer to use a custom template, you could include the bundles as follows (as in the [default template](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html#L51-L53)):

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

And you can just add your host to the `src`. For the CSS see [default template - CSS](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html#L18-L20]). You should also set `inject: false` in that case, so it doesn't add them a second time.